# How do I delete the expired Oauth refresh tokens from mysql the using jdbc tokenstore?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have tried with

```
tokenStore.removeRefreshToken("token");
```

But I need to delete the refresh token on its expiry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an out-of-the-box that automatically removes the expired token. You will have to do a custom implementation.

One of the option would be to schedule a house-keeping task that purges the expired token from the database.

You can refer to this article for more information
https://www.baeldung.com/registration-token-cleanup

Comment: Thanks for the solution , manually deleted the token using batch process